# Storing the frame of a video before the current frame?

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I currently have a piece of code which displays video and I'm trying to extend it so that it shows the difference between the current and previous frame, so that it detects motion. I know I'm going to have to use the `absdiff()` function to show the contrast between the two images, but I'm not sure how to store the previous frame as a `Mat`. Could somebody have a look at my code below and show me where I should add this 'previous frame' code, and what I should write. I'm assuming it won't take long, I just can't find any tutorials for this online...

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

// ********************************************************

public class CaptureVideo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // load the Core OpenCV library by name

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    // create video capture device object

    VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture();

    // try to use the hardware device if present

    int CAM_TO_USE = 0;

    // create a new image object

    Mat matFrame = new Mat();

    // try to open first capture device (0)

    try {
        cap.open(CAM_TO_USE);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println("No webcam attached");

        // otherwise try opening a video file 

        try{
            cap.open("files/video.mp4");
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println("No video file found");
        }
    }

    // if the a video capture source is now open

    if (cap.isOpened())
    {

        // create a new window object

        Imshow ims = new Imshow("From video source ... ");

        boolean keepProcessing = true;

        while (keepProcessing)
        {   
            // grab the next frame from video source

            cap.grab();

            // decode and return the grabbed video frame

            cap.retrieve(matFrame);

            // if the frame is valid (not end of video for example)

            if (!(matFrame.empty()))
            {
                // *** to any processing here*** 

                // display image with a delay of 40ms (i.e. 1000 ms / 25 = 25 fps)

                ims.showImage(matFrame);
                Thread.sleep(40);
            } else { 
                keepProcessing = false;
            }
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("error cannot open any capture source - exiting");

    }

    // close down the camera correctly

    cap.release();

  }
}
```

I've tried adding the following code after either of the `else` statements, but all that's produced is a black screen (which I assume is because 'previousFrame' is just a duplicate of 'matFrame'):

```
            previousFrame = matFrame;

            Core.absdiff(matFrame, previousFrame, diffFrame);

            ims.showImage(diffFrame);
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: kindly can u have a look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237543/how-to-capture-avi-file-frame-by-frame-and-display-it-in-jframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `previousFrame = matFrame;` makes `previousFrame` **point** to `matFrame`.  You are not **copying** the matrix over - both `previousFrame` and `matFrame` are referring to the same object.  Therefore, you are essentially subtracting the matrix with itself, which is why you are getting a black frame.

You need to do a **proper** copy and so you need to **clone** the matrix using [`Mat.clone()`](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#clone()).  However, if you want to find the difference between two frames, bear in mind that we need to read in at least two frames for this to happen.  We can't really find a difference frame when we read in only the first frame of the video, and so we should have a check to see if this is the first frame or not.  If it's the first frame, just display the normal frame accordingly.  After that point, we can display the difference frame by ensuring that we copy the previous frame before reading in the next frame.

As such, do this instead for your loop:

```
   // ****** Change - add a flag to check to see if the first frame has been read
   boolean firstFrame = true;

   // ****** Change - declare previous frame here
   Mat previousFrame;
   while (keepProcessing)
    {   
        // ****** Change - Save previous frame before getting next one
        // Only do this if the first frame has passed
        if (!firstFrame)
            previousFrame = matFrame.clone();

        // grab the next frame from video source
        cap.grab();

        // decode and return the grabbed video frame
        cap.retrieve(matFrame);

        // if the frame is valid (not end of video for example)
        if (!(matFrame.empty()))
        {
            // **** Change - If we are on the first frame, only show that and
            // set the flag to false
            if (firstFrame) {
                ims.showImage(matFrame);
                firstFrame = false;
            }
            // ***** Change - now show absolute difference after first frame
            else {                
                Core.absdiff(matFrame, previousFrame, diffFrame);
                ims.showImage(diffFrame);                 
            }

            // display image with a delay of 40ms (i.e. 1000 ms / 25 = 25 fps)                
            Thread.sleep(40);
        } else { 
            keepProcessing = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Worked perfectly and really well explained.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help! That assignment that you were doing assigning the previous frame to be the next frame is a subtle error that a lot of Java coders make. Doing an equals operation always refers to an object and doesn't deep copy. You can make the assignment operator actually copy things over if you overloaded that operator in a language like C++ but Java doesn't support operator overloading. Good luck!

Comment: Do you ever do some form of online tuition? I'm currently working on a project but struggling to figure out how to do it...

Comment: @Zetland - Indeed I do.  Hit me up on codementor: http://www.codementor.io/rayryeng

Comment: @rayryeng kindly can u have a look at my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237543/how-to-capture-avi-file-frame-by-frame-and-display-it-in-jframe

Comment: @rmaik - The post is closed.  I can't do anything until it's reopen.

Comment: @rayryeng thans for the reply...here is the same quest. i posted in other website the forum of opencv: http://answers.opencv.org/question/58281/how-to-display-the-grabbed-video-frame-inside-jframe/

Comment: @rmaik - I'm not a member of that community and I prefer to answer the question here.  Hope you get your question solved!